# Error: Permission denied to access property "then" errorin angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting `Error: Permission denied to access property "then"` error in angular2.

I have added **"outDir": "dist"** in **tsconfig.json** file because I want to move all the compiled file in "dist" dir, before the change it is working fine.

I have added below code in index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>:: XXXX ::</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <base href="/alean/">
    <script>
      System.import('dist/app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```